# WPF не работает MinWidth/MinHeight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Не работает MinWidth/MinHeight. Что делать?
Xaml:
1) Работает

```
<Border Background="Aqua" >
    <Polyline StrokeEndLineCap="Round" MinHeight="{Binding GraphHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding GraphWidth}" StrokeThickness="2"  Stroke="OrangeRed" Points="0,0 20,20 30,50"/>
</Border>
```

...
2. Работает

```
<Border Background="Aqua" >
    <Polyline MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" Stroke="OrangeRed" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="2" Points="{Binding Path=Points}"/>
</Border>
```

3. Не работает (красный фон)

```
<Border Background="Red" >
    <Polyline MinHeight="{Binding GraphHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding GraphWidth}" Stroke="BlueViolet" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="2" Points="{Binding Path=Points}"/>
</Border>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

VM.cs:

```
 int _GraphWidth = 100;
        public int GraphWidth
        {
            get => _GraphWidth;
        }
        int _GraphHeight = 100;
        public int GraphHeight
        {
            get => _GraphHeight;
        }
```

Для случая (1) бинд на MinWidth/MinHeight работает, для случая (3) нет. В чём проблема?

Comment: Что значит не работает? Из вопроса непонятно чего вы ожидаете и что фактически не так в результате.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, для третьего случая (красный фон на картинке) не установилось MinWidth/MinHeight.